# Is it fine to encrypt if there are cross-drive NTFS junctions?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, truecrypt, ntfs-junction

I was thinking of encrypting the whole disk or only my data partition `D:`. However, I have NTFS junctions on the system partition `C:` linking to `D:`. More precisely, I made a junction to point my user profile directory to a directory in `D:`, effectively storing my user profile on the other partition.

My concern is, if I encrypt `D:`, my user profile cannot be loaded before mounting it with TrueCrypt, which may require logging in my account which cannot happen before mounting the partition.

Is it actually possible to encrypt `D:` and be able to use Windows normally in this case? Any other ways other than performing a whole disk encryption?

---

**Edit:** I don't have my system partition encrypted. If I have to, I would rather encrypt the whole disk.

I also have Ubuntu installed on the extended partition, which is not encrypted either.

Comment: Is your system partition encrypted? If it is then you could encrypt D: and configure it as a [System Favorite Volume](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-favorites).

Comment: @gm2 No. If I have to encrypt the system partition, I would rather just encrypt the whole disk.